# Using Python Selenium and IE driver I don't succeed to find an element

Tags: python, selenium

Using Python Selenium and IE driver I don't succeed to find  an element

This is a part of the HTML code:

```
<div class="loginTextCss">
    <label for="j_username">User Name:</label>
    <br />
    <input id="j_username" name="j_username" type="text" value="" style="font-size:16px; width:170px;" />
    <br /><br />
    <label for="j_password">Password:</label>
    <br />
    <input type="password" id="j_password" name="j_password" value="" style="font-size:16px; width:170px;" />
    <br />
    <div style="font-size:11;">
        <input id="rememberMe" type="checkbox" name="_spring_security_remember_me" title="Remember me on this computer" />
        <label for="rememberMe" title="Remember me on this computer">Remember me on this computer</label>
    </div>
</div>
```

My code is:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys

browser = webdriver.Ie()
browser.get('http://192.168.58.32/asset-manager-web/')
browser.maximize_window()
element = browser.find_element_by_id('j_username')
```

And I got the error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#11>", line 1, in <module>
    browser.find_element_by_id("j_username")
  File "C:\Python33\lib\site-packages\selenium-2.41.0-py3.3.egg\selenium\webdriver\remote\webdriver.py", line 199, in find_element_by_id
    return self.find_element(by=By.ID, value=id_)
  File "C:\Python33\lib\site-packages\selenium-2.41.0-py3.3.egg\selenium\webdriver\remote\webdriver.py", line 655, in find_element
    {'using': by, 'value': value})['value']
  File "C:\Python33\lib\site-packages\selenium-2.41.0-py3.3.egg\selenium\webdriver\remote\webdriver.py", line 166, in execute
    self.error_handler.check_response(response)
  File "C:\Python33\lib\site-packages\selenium-2.41.0-py3.3.egg\selenium\webdriver\remote\errorhandler.py", line 164, in check_response
    raise exception_class(message, screen, stacktrace)
selenium.common.exceptions.NoSuchElementException: Message: 'Unable to find element with id == j_username'
```

Someone knows what is the problem?

Thanks

Comment: Try FireFox and see if it works (i use java ) this is the first step you should try then if it work try diffrent path or it will be better to use css selector and not xpath

Comment: Ok thanks, the problem is that this application is suppot only IE 7 to 11.

Comment: so you need to search tools as firebug and xpath checker for IE as i remember there are some tools http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=18359 this is what i found using google

Comment: I tried to debug by myself and I got this error message for the command find_element:

{'status': 23, 'sessionId': 'de8eea06-2887-49da-a6d7-a726ec50c012', 'value': {'message': 'Unable to find element on closed window'}}

Comment: try to find element by xpath to see it is not null xptah "//*" or better css cslector

Comment: I tried to find an element on yahoo.com on Firefox it works but with IE it doesn't work, I'm using IE 11 maybe selenium doesn't support it

Comment: i think it is only the element, try other element or try other selenium version

Comment: I tried several elements and it doesn't work I think that selenium think that the window of the browser is closed because I got for browser.current_window_handle() an error: 'Window is closed' and really the window is not closed

Comment: if it is a popup (i think it is not the case ) you need to set the focus

Comment: did you try to change selenium version or IE version ?

Comment: I found a workaround for IE11 in selenium page but I don't really understand:
https://code.google.com/p/selenium/wiki/InternetExplorerDriver

can you help me to understand what is a DWORD and I don't find the PATH HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Wow6432Node\Microsoft\Internet Explorer\Main\FeatureControl\FEATURE_BFCACH

Thanks

Comment: I found how to add a new key, so I did it I will check now if it really helps

Comment: It didn't help I have still the same error I tried also with IE10 and it doesn't work.